Switching research line at 2+years in post-doc
I am 2+ years in my first postdoc. In my PhD and beginning of my post-doc, my expertise was multidisciplinary: it linked different thematics. However I am getting a bit “bored” by this research line, I would like to do something else. Also, I would also like to gain more expertise in a given field (become more specialized).
I am very interested in a “specialist” research line “A”, which uses for a part some tools I had to use in my multidisciplinary research line. However, the questions treated in “A” are very different from the ones I treated before, and I have no expertise at all in “A” right now: I clearly need to learn.
I have a bit more than 1 year remaining in my current post-doc with an advisor that has no expertise in A but knows many mathematical tools that could be useful there. I have some post-doc friends working in A I could relatively easily reach out. Of course I could find another post-doc after this one.

My question: is it risky to make such a move toward a research line I have no expertise in at this stage of my career ?

Important paragraph for context: what stresses me out is that I feel I will lose a lot of productivity by doing the move, and I’m worried about the impact on my career especially given the fact it occurs at 2+ years of post doc. I am saying this because I still feel like I am not an expert of a given topic at this stage of my career. The reason is that I worked on different topics, establishing connections between them, so it is more I know “a bit” of different fields than a lot in one field. I had some nice results (in my opinion) in this multidisciplinary research, but the big drewback of this research is that it makes it really hard to become fully autonomous: without experts complementing my own knowledge I can be stuck in my research. This is why I feel like I really need to gain some specialist expertise. Another reason behind my worry is that I am not super productive in research outputs. In my field, the most productive have ~20 papers at my carrer stage (with a few of them being strong papers) while I only have 10 (my situation is not a catastrophe -- I recall I’m comparing to the very most productive -- but it is not great, I’m quite slow). To compensate a bit for that, I had some nice results in my PhD (my community was very interested in them), and I will put a pre-print soon which I think is a nice paper (in my subjective opinion though). I also have published other papers from my post-doc (they are definitely not groundbreaking, but I would say "fine" in quality). Finally, I plan to find a faculty position: I applied this year and had good ranking after interview to get tenured, but not sufficiently high to get the job for sure unfortunately. The reason I am explaining all this is so that you have the whole context about my situation to evaluate if what I want to do is risky or is actually a natural move (perhaps it is normal to extend to new horizons and lose productivity by doing so).
I find it very hard to judge if what I want to do is a silly decision/too risky, or actually expected and a good one. I am really stressed by my current academic career and I don’t want to ruin it on a bad career move.

Related, possible duplicate: How can I switch from field X to field Y after getting my PhD?

Ultimately, it is up to you and there is no right or wrong answer a priori.
Personally, I switched research areas at several points during my career: my MS (disease ecology), PhD (ecotoxicology), my postdoc (a wind energy and disease ecology project), and then my permanent research position (invasive species management).
Throughout all the areas, I used and developed a quantitively skill set that has served me well.
What do you want to do?
Be a narrow-focused academic at a major research university?
Teach at a teaching institution?
Work at a government lab?
A narrow and highly focused research area may help you with the first area, but not the other options that often favor broad backgrounds and skill sets.

Switching at this point seems overly risky. Giving up productive lines, even if you aren't among the "most productive" seems sub-optimal.
OTOH, working on boring things isn't fun, but the time isn't that long until your next career move.
Your supervisor, assuming you have one, should be able to give valuable input.
But, if you can parlay the current situation into a permanent position you will have more freedom of action. Make your supervisor happy, I'd suggest.
However, it is possible and advisable to keep a notebook on "ideas" that come to you on other topics. Make notes there and refer to them regularly, updating as you get insights.
