Not being specialist of a precise topic (but having a broader perspective): is it a bad thing for an experienced post-doc
I finished my PhD a few years ago and I just finished my second year of post-doc.
My research has been quite multidisciplinary and I am getting increasingly worried to not have a label of being the expert in field X, but rather as the person that works "in between" fields A, B, C. When I say I work "in between", it is in the sense that I have sometimes papers on field A, B or C exclusively, and sometimes having a paper joining A, B and C.
One advantage in being multidisciplinary is that you get the broader scope of the challenges of the field and it gives the ability to identify good research questions (this is at least what I feel in my daily work). However, the big drawback is (in my opinion) the difficulty to be fully autonomous in actually treating the research questions. This is because I often really need to talk to an expert that complements my own knowledge or redirects me to the good literature: without this I can easily get stuck (or I will be forced to treat a much simpler version of the problem that will be significantly less interesting).
My question is: does this lack of specialist expertise is something I should be worried of and fix (in particular because I can lack autonomy if I want to treat )? When I compare my positioning to the one of I believe are "good postdocs" I sometimes feel a bit bad because they have a clear "label" for their research while I don't really have.

Probably depends on the positions you apply for. Personally, in my technical staff hiring at a US national lab, I value multidisciplinary folks. I know that 10 years from now you will be working something else and having breadth will make it easier for you to contribute to a range of projects. But, some other posted position - who knows? You are where you are, so look for positions that match where you are.

You've had a similar question recently. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/211030/switching-research-line-at-2years-in-post-doc Seems like you're at cross-roads for life.  You may want to look for answer within yourself rather than internet help pages.

Either way, you need to produce, either original research, teaching, or applications in public or private research or industry. Whether generalist or hyperspecialized, continue growing always.

This is an answer from theoretical mathematics.  I believe it applies to other theoretical disciplines, but much less to experimental or even computational ones; in particular my colleagues doing mathematical modelling don't share this view.
If you're aiming for a research-oriented academic position, one of the main reasons most departments have for having such a position is that you will be advising PhD students.  For their dissertation, a PhD students needs to solve a problem that other researchers have already tried to solve and failed(*).  (If a problem is interesting, other people have almost by definition at least thought about trying to solve it!)  Think back to when you first started working on a research problem.  How capable were you?  Now drop an entire order of magnitude, because you are among the minority of PhDs who managed to obtain a research position afterwards, and your students, just statistically speaking, are not as strong in research as you are.(**)
How in the world is a PhD student supposed to solve a problem when more experienced researchers have failed to?  A PhD student has two advantages.  The first is time.  However, in a theoretical discipline, this is not the decisive advantage that it can be in experimental disciplines, where much worthwhile research hasn't been done only because no one has had the labor (and the lab resources) to do it.  A graduate student needs a second competitive advantage to write a dissertation, and that is access to your advice.  You need to have some kind of expertise so that your students can solve problems other researchers have been interested in solving but not succeeded.
Now this expertise can be but isn't always deep knowledge of a single subfield.  This expertise could also be a strong understanding of how to apply techniques from one field in a particular different context.  It could also be a strong understanding of a particular object of study, that you study from multiple different perspectives.  Given you have published multiple papers, you must have some form of this expertise, but you do need it to be concentrated enough that it remains a competitive advantage filtered through a less capable student.
(*) Actually, this isn't true; many problems turn out to be interesting after they are solved, not before, but then you need the expertise to spot such problems.
(**) In my department, no theoretical mathematics student has ever gone on to a research-oriented position after their PhD in the entire history of the program; many mid-to-low ranked departments have maybe one PhD graduate in a decade going on to a research-oriented position.

Thanks. My current issue is that I think I can have good idea of research projects (I'm somewhat autonomous there). The issue is that I sometimes lack the technical skills to do them alone, as a consequence of having the broad but unspecialized knowledge. Some of these skills are difficult to learn without having an expert around. For instance I can recognize how techniques from field A can help to solve issues in field B, but without collaborating with someone in field A I can really struggle in solving the problem (I might be forced to attack a much simpler version of it).

I don't have enough vision to know if this is "normal" for a multidisciplinary researcher or if I should be worried by this.

It's perfectly normal to have dozens of problems one has thought about but can't solve.

"Good" problems are often too hard for one person to solve. Look at nearly any modern paper, and you'll see more than one author. Often, at least one person contributed an essential skill others didn't have. I think you're struggling somewhat under the old model of "the lone researcher" who locks themselves in a lab/office and comes out years later with a breakthrough. Nearly all science nowadays is done by networks of people, which it sounds like you excel at constructing. Do you want to hit every problem with a hammer, or know which tool you need for a problem and know where to find it?

@Eden: Mathematics is not a science.  A significant number of papers have only one author.  I can't think of a major breakthrough that hasn't been driven by the genius of one or two people, even if a few more are involved in the work.

@Alexander Woo I was responding to the OP who didn't specify their field, not your post per se. My comment probably should have been attached to the OP's. My understanding of mathematics though, is that even if a paper is single-authored, the field is still highly collaborative. The story of Andrew Wiles' proof of Fermat's last theorem is odd for modern math because he worked in isolation and secrecy so long. But I may be wrong.

While also technically being a theorist, let me give a perspective differing from the one in the other answer. Aside of solving well-defined problems, another type of researcher's job is investigating various directions that haven't yet been explored for a variety of reasons: not being viewed as promising, very new and lacking human resources (nobody had time), omission (nobody tried applying A to B because haven't had the knowledge of both), etc. While this type of research ("go see what's out there", with a rough idea of expected outcome) may naturally seem less "noble" than solving some isolated well-defined problem that everyone was aware of for decades, it constitutes a great portion of science as well.
In order to lead this type of work you need some of the following qualities:

Intuition/knowledge for identifying interesting/important/impactful directions.
Being able to adequately estimate success probability and amount of efforts required to achieve results.
Knowing the right sources of extra knowledge (people, literature, SE, etc.) and how to use them.
Ability to manage/guide/motivate people.

Now, while I haven't listed here the particular quality you mentioned (being an expert in smth), having it does help a lot. Good news is that having some solid conceptual high-level understanding may often be enough to direct those capable of investigating all the nuances. And yet my experience is that all the good PIs are capable of brainstorming some kind of specific problems (it's OK if for other types of problems they refer people to somewhere else).
The piece of wisdom I got early on when asking a similar question to my boss in the beginning of my postdoc was in the lines of:
By the end of your postdoc, there should exist a little area of your expertise where you are the world champion. It can be tiny. It can be isolated. It can be unpopular. (All of these problems are solvable with some marketing efforts.) This is what you're going to be hired for.
We may or may not agree with this perspective but so far my experience mostly confirms this vision. I think it is very much worth spending some time and creating such an area for yourself, using various available means (learning from others, studying on your own, etc.). And again, I personally think that conceptual understating of what's going on in this area of yours is the main factor, so do not let the lack of some specific technical skills scare you off. Once you create this "scientific core", all the "softer" qualities and skills will readily magnify it.

I've made my career in multidisciplinary science and working in the interstices of a few fields. It has both advantages and disadvantages.
If you are going to make it work, you need to become known as someone who is good at what you do, a reliable collaborator, and easy to work with. You'll be the person who others want as a co-PI or research project leader because you can make their work relevant to others, pull different disciplines together and do things that they can't do alone. For a multi-disciplinary researcher, it is even more important than it is for disciplinary specialists not to be seen as a prima donna.
At the same time, it is very important to be publishing your own work as first author regularly and proposing collaborations, not just tagging along. When all your work is collaborative, it can be too easy to let this slip and simply be a co-author on other people's papers and grant applications. This is the path to becoming a perpetual postdoc: you'll be seen as useful, but not a leader.
It will also help if you are flexible, open to different opportunities, and have lots of ideas for research you'd like to do rather than being someone who wants to pursue one idea relentlessly. You'll be able to see what different grant agencies are looking for and find funding from a variety of sources. You'll be able to apply for jobs in more than one field and be taken seriously, but you might not be the most obvious pick for any of them.
Advantages:

Variety
Collaboration
Job security in hard times: if your department is cut, you already have collaborators in other departments and can move. If one source of funds dries up, you'll have other options.

Disadvantages:

It will be harder to make a name for yourself. Instead of consistently sending your best work to one or two great journals, you will be scattering your work and you won't easily develop a consistent group of readers who know your name and follow your work. Instead of building your networks in one field by going to the same disciplinary conference every year, you will be going to a different one each time, depending on what you are working on that year.
While there will be more jobs that you can apply for, you'll have to work hard to convince the hiring committees that you are the best fit. You won't have so strong a profile within any given narrow discipline as some of the other applicants. [But there are occasional opportunities for which a multidisciplinary profile will be seen as an advantage].

